# Qt errors while building for android

Tags: android, c++, qt, build, qt-creator

when I try to build my project in Qt creator for android, these errors occur:

```
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Qt.Class
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

this is my `.pro` file content:

```
QT += qml quick

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    downloader.cpp \
    filemanager.cpp

HEADERS += \
    downloader.h \
    filemanager.h

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

QT += network
QT += xml
QT += gui
# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH = /home/muhammad/Qt5.9.0/5.9/android_armv7/qml/

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
#QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradlew \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew.bat \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradlew \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew.bat

ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
```

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As the error has shown, you need to update Gradle to at least 2.14.1 https://gradle.org/releases

Comment: I have solved that but this in not my main problem. The issue is importing Qt modules